# C# Instantiate Vector3 Problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner of learning programming
Instantiate(o, new Vector3(LocateX, LocateY, 0), transform.rotation);
In this code Visual Studio 2022 keeps telling me there is an error with LocateX and LocateY...
Please help me
using Unity
error code : CS0165

FixedCode

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using UnityEngine;

public class OXScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int clickNumber;
    public GameObject o;
    public int spotNumber;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        clickNumber= 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void SpawnO()
    {
        //  1,   2,  3, y = 3
        //  4,   5,  6, y = 0
        //  7,   8,  9, y = -3
        // x=-3 x=0 x=3

        float LocateX = 0;
        float LocateY = 0;
        int ix = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
        {
            if (clickNumber == 0 && spotNumber == i)
            {
                // y
                if(1 <= i && i <= 3 )
                {
                    LocateY = 3;
                } else if(4 <= i && i <= 6)
                {
                    LocateY = 0;
                } else if (7 <= i && i <= 9)
                {
                    LocateY = -3;
                }
                //x
                if (ix == (i - 1) % 3)
                {
                    LocateX = -3;
                } else if (ix + 1 == (i - 1) % 3)
                {
                    LocateX = 0;
                } else if (ix + 2 == (i - 1) % 3)
                {
                    LocateX = 3;
                }

                Instantiate(o, new Vector3(LocateX, LocateY, 0), transform.rotation);
                spotNumber ++;
                clickNumber ++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem Solved!!

I know my code is not clean at all so thank you for helping noob everyone!

Comment: Please provide the *precise* error message rather than just "there is error with LocateX and LocateY".

Comment: There is no case for `else` so eventually `LocateX` and `LocateY` are tried to be used without being initialized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialization is required before using local variables.

```
    float LocateX = 0;
    float LocateY = 0;
```

Comment: I believe the correct term would be *assignment*, and specifically *definite assignment*. See [chapter 9.4 from the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using *modulo arithemtics* here: for

```
    1,        2,       3    y = 3
    4,        5,       6    y = 0
    7,        8,       9    y = -3
    x = -3    x = 0    x = 3
```

we can put

```
   x = ((i - 1) % 3 - 1) * 3
   y = (1 - (i - 1) / 3) * 3
```

And get

```
public void SpawnO() {
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
    if (clickNumber == 0 && spotNumber == i) {
      int LocateX = ((i - 1) % 3 - 1) * 3
      int LocateY = (1 - (i - 1) / 3) * 3;

      Instantiate(o, new Vector3(LocateX, LocateY, 0), transform.rotation);

      spotNumber += 1;
    }
  }
}
```